# How to setup and control the dynamixels for the three omni-wheels?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ΧΜ430-W210-T motors. I can't find anywhere something that will solve my problem...  Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358954/how-to-setup-and-control-the-dynamixels-for-the-three-omni-wheels?/) by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2020-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. I will suggest you to checkout [Dynamixel WorkBench](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_workbench/) to familiarize yourself.
   After that checkout [Dynamixel SDK](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_sdk/overview/) that will show you how to command your motors.  There are very good examples given already. I think they are more than enough atleast to move a robot and an example([Python](https://github.com/tonnesfn/DynamixelSDK/tree/master/python) and [CPP](https://github.com/tonnesfn/DynamixelSDK/tree/master/c%2B%2B/example/)) how to use dynamixel motors and SDK.
2. Calculate robots velocity commands. A nice tutorial can be found [here](https://yainnoware.blogspot.com/2019/03/three-wheeled-holonomic-robot-theory.html) and its corrresponding [ros example](https://github.com/YugAjmera/teleop_keyboard_omni3/blob/master/teleop_keyboard_omni3.py).
3. Now just connect step 1 and 2 and your robot should move.

---

Originally posted by [Tahir M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23517/tahir-m./) with karma: 213 on 2020-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-08-11**:
Thank you very much Tahir, I will try it and mark this answer